# Perl:Match a string and delete all but first occurrence

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file in perl that has the following content

```
abc
text1 
text2
text3
abc
text4
text5
abc
abc
```

Final output:

```
abc
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

I want to use a perl one liner or a script to retain the 1st abc and delete the rest. 
In my script I am using pattern matching operator `m?/abc/` to find the 1st pattern but not able to figure out a way to delete the rest. Please help me with the same

Comment: Does it always appear by itself on a line, and you want to delete the entire line?  (Also please undo your latest edit, which unfixed the formatting...)

Comment: Ok I removed my latest edit. Ya what I am doing is concatenating a bunch of xml files which have a string xml version on line1. In the concatenated file, I need this line only once and so I need to delete the other occurrences and retain only the first

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to delete the entire line containing the second and subsequent occurrences of `abc`:

```
perl -ne 'print if !/abc/ || !$n++' < infile > outfile
```

If you want to delete lines containing `abc` *and nothing else*, change `/abc/` to `/^abc$/`.

Comment: When I try this I am getting "xml" event not found, though infile has xml. This is my line 1          <?xml version =1.0" encoding "UTF"?> And I am trying this command perl -ne 'print if !/xml version/ || !$n++' < infile > outfile

Comment: Are you on Mac/Unix or Windows?

Comment: Ah.  Then change the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Should the <? before xml version in the string be accounted for in the one-liner?

Comment: Up to you.  It's always good practice to use the tightest possible conditions, so I would say yes.

Comment: perl -ne "print if !/xml version/ || !$n++" file1.txt > file2.txt

Comment: Well...  It works fine for me.  Are you using a regular cmd.exe command shell?

Comment: Weird, I thought that was only used back in like Win95/98...  And I think my command should work with that anyway.  Try starting a cmd.exe if you can.

Comment: Ok will do that. Thanks